# Add new dictionary values to an existing csv

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to add 2 new columns to an existing file in the same program. The csv is generated by the previous function.

After looking at many answers here, I tried this, but it doesn't work because I couldn't find any answers using the `csv dict writer` in them, they were all about `csv writer`. This just creates a new file with these 2 columns in them. Can I get some help with this?

```
for me, sp in zip(meds, specs):
    print(me.text, sp.text)
    dict2 = {"Medicines": me.text, "Specialities": sp.text}
    with open(f'Infusion_t{zip_add}.csv', 'r') as read, \
            open(f'(Infusion_final{zip_add}.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(read)
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict2.keys())
        for row in reader:
            if not header_added:
                w.writeheader()
                header_added = True
            row.append(w.writerow(dict2))
```

Comment: Your nested loops are going to create a cross product between the lists and the CSV file, is that what you want? Or should they be in 1-to-1 correspondence?

Comment: for 1 value in the row in the previous file, these ought to add multiple rows for the same index, but in 2 different columns. I didn't get to that part, because it doesn't even write it as of now. Like the previous file has a singer's name..this is getting his songs and albums..something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the new columns to `row`, then write `row` to the output file. You don't need the dictionary or `DictWriter`.

You can also open the output file just once before the loop, and write the header there, rather than each time through the main loop.

```
with open(f'(Infusion_final{zip_add}.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', ..., 'Medicines', 'Specalities']) # replace colX with the names of the original columns
    for me, sp in zip(meds, specs):
        print(me.text, sp.text)
        with open(f'Infusion_t{zip_add}.csv', 'r') as read:                
            reader = csv.reader(read)
            for row in reader:
                row.append(me.text)
                row.append(sp.text)
                w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: You were correct, it repeats the headers. I should open it just once. Thanks a ton, was trying this for an hour now.

Comment: Your `header_added` variable should prevent it from repeating headers. But this way is simpler.